# How to test at runtime if a block is currently executed on the main queue?

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I am using an API where it is not entirely clear if the block is always executed on the main queue. If it is not, then I need to call the main queue synchronously.

How can I check if the block is already executing on the main queue? `dispatch_get_current_queue()` is deprecated. Must I use `dispatch_get_specific()` to get an comparable identifier?

Answer (score 3):

The unique thing about the main queue is that it is always matched exactly to the main thread. So you can use `[NSThread isMainThread]`.

Comment: Also possible using `pthread_main_np` if you're not using Objective-C.